# Implementing a custom move in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I'm using Optaplanner to make a schedule for a school. Every works good, except that it sometimes have gaps between the lessons, which I do not want. I have rules for punishing this but I think the search space is so big that it will take quite a while before it "fixes" this.
Is it possible to tell Optaplanner to try out some "selected/calculated" moves first and then continue with the moves it is supposed to do?
I'm using the time grain patterns with this.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do, but not recommended. There is good literature on the subject here: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html

I would start first by experimenting with *configuring* the generic moves that are provided out-of-the-box in optaplanner, which you can do by editing the XML file included with the distribution.

If a custom move is really what you need, you can refer to the docs above, but it is much harder to avoid bugs this way and you will want to enable *full assert* to double-check that score corruption is not occurring after implementation.

Comment: I would just add that there is a much much more recent version of OptaPlanner documentation. Specifically, the up-to-date version of the page you point to is available here: https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to accept the suggested edit.